# What happens if we throw the observer in a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, observers, event-horizon, quantum-measurements

Sorry if this sounds like a silly question, but what would happen if a scientist observes Schrodinger's cat alive, but is then thrown into a black hole before he has leaked any information to the environment.

Then later a second scientist observes the cat - can he observe it as dead this time, since the first scientist and his information can't leave the black hole to contradict?

That is, is a wavefunction allowed to show two different faces to two observers so long as they are never allowed to compare notes because of an event horizon? Is exiling information behind an event horizon the same as erasing it?

Comment: A better model is that the cat lives or dies because of decoherence. No observer is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two measurement results must be consistent, so the second scientist will see the cat alive. It doesn't matter whether the first scientist's knowledge leaks into the environment or not, only that it exists.

Tossing the first scientist into a black hole makes their knowledge inaccessible, but doesn't erase it or undo the measurement.

Comment: Thank you - I was kind of trying to understand how the Wigner's friend thought experiment and delayed quantum eraser experiment would interact with each other.

Comment: Now that I said it, I found this - https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353900/in-the-delayed-choice-quantum-eraser-what-would-happen-if-we-were-to-send-the-s